Raster is drawn only partly in tmap
Some of my maps that contain rasters get drawn partly only. The southern part of the map is cut off. It looks like some memory limit, but I have no idea if it is so. Another option is something concerning reprojection and bbox... Nevertheless, other rasters of the same crs work well in this project.

library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(maps)

raster.file <-   tempfile()
download.file("https://github.com/andliszmmu/storage/raw/main/copernicus_2000.tif", raster.file, mode="wb")

ocean.pal   <- '#afdff9'
prj         <- CRS("+proj=eqdc +lat_0=57 +lon_0=46.8 +lat_1=69.4367 +lat_2=51.3043 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=sphere +units=m +no_defs")
map_bbox    <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -1700000, ymin = -1780000, xmax = 1040000, ymax = 2330000), crs = prj)

land        <- st_as_sf(maps::map("world", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
land        <- land[land$ID=='Russia',]
land        <- st_transform(land, prj)

model        <- raster(paste0(raster.file))

  tm =  
    tm_shape(land, bbox = map_bbox) +
    tm_fill(col = ocean.pal) +
    tm_shape(model)+
    tm_raster(style='fixed',
              breaks = c(0, 35,45,55,67,75,85,95,112, 200),
              palette=c('lightgreen', 'yellow', 'red', 'grey', 'white', 'blue', '#f21deb', 'darkgreen', 'green'),
              labels=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"),
              alpha = 1,
              #n=5,
              stretch.palette = FALSE,
              title = 'Landscape classification',
              legend.show = TRUE,
              legend.reverse = TRUE,
              legend.z=0) +
    tm_layout(frame = T,
              frame.lwd = 2,
              inner.margins = c(0,0,0,0),
              outer.margins = c(0.07, 0.127, 0.07, 0.112),
              asp = 39/56,
              legend.frame = T,
              legend.format = list(text.separator = "–"),
              legend.frame.lwd = 1,
              legend.outside = F,
              legend.position = c(0.001, 0.999),
              legend.just = c("left", "top"),
              legend.width = -0.32,
              legend.height = 0.9,
              legend.text.size = 0.7,
              legend.title.size = 1.1,
              legend.bg.color = "white",
              title.size = 0.7,
              title.bg.color = 'white',
              title.position = c('left', 'bottom')) +
    tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE,
                 max.raster = c(plot = 1e8, view = 1e8))
  
tm
    

I checked documentation and the web, but had not found solution.
Parameters of this raster are:
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2000, 1441, 2882000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0343, 0.0179  (x, y)
extent     : 19.64043, 69.06673, 41.19558, 76.99558  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : copernicus_2000.tif 
names      : copernicus_2000 
values     : 20, 200  (min, max)
Raster downsampling (resolution <- 0.0343, 0.0343) did not help.

I am not so familiar with tmap, but I tried to remove the first and second line of tm :   tm_shape(land, bbox = map_bbox) +  tm_fill(col = ocean.pal) + and the southern classification show up. Maybe it's a bbox or crs issue.

likely a red herring but ?raster::plot has a maxpixels parameter of either 500000 or 100000 (defaults) that may or may not want to be set.

Those non-conformal projections can be difficult to negotiate. Curious that none of your other data were clipped but I'm assuming none extend as far south as the problem raster?
Either way, here is a solution. It involves raster::extend()ing the southern extent of your raster:
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(maps)

# PROJ4 string
prj <- "+proj=eqdc +lat_0=57 +lon_0=46.8 +lat_1=69.4367 +lat_2=51.3043 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=sphere +units=m +no_defs"

# Load .tif as raster from working directory, previously downloaded from
# https://github.com/andliszmmu/storage/raw/main/copernicus_2000.tif
r <- raster("data/copernicus_2000.tif")

# Return extent of raster
st_bbox(r)
#     xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax 
# 19.64043 41.19558 69.06673 76.99558 

# Extend the southern extent of raster e.g. change 41.19558 to 30
r <- extend(r, extent(19.64043, 69.06673, 30, 76.99558)) # xmin xmax ymin ymax 

map_bbox <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -1700000, ymin = -1780000, xmax = 1040000, ymax = 2330000), crs = prj)

ocean.pal <- '#afdff9'
land <- st_as_sf(maps::map("world", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
land <- land[land$ID=='Russia',]
land <- st_transform(land, prj)

tm =
  tm_shape(land, bbox = map_bbox) +
  tm_fill(col = ocean.pal) +
  tm_shape(r)+
  tm_raster(style = 'fixed',
            breaks = c(0, 35,45,55,67,75,85,95,112, 200),
            palette=c('lightgreen', 'yellow', 'red', 'grey', 'white', 'blue', '#f21deb', 'darkgreen', 'green'),
            labels=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"),
            alpha = 1,
            #n=5,
            stretch.palette = FALSE,
            title = 'Landscape classification',
            legend.show = TRUE,
            legend.reverse = TRUE,
            legend.z=0) +
  tm_layout(frame = T,
            frame.lwd = 2,
            inner.margins = c(0,0,0,0),
            outer.margins = c(0.07, 0.127, 0.07, 0.112),
            asp = 39/56,
            legend.frame = T,
            legend.format = list(text.separator = "–"),
            legend.frame.lwd = 1,
            legend.outside = F,
            legend.position = c(0.001, 0.999),
            legend.just = c("left", "top"),
            legend.width = -0.32,
            legend.height = 0.9,
            legend.text.size = 0.7,
            legend.title.size = 1.1,
            legend.bg.color = "white",
            title.size = 0.7,
            title.bg.color = 'white',
            title.position = c('left', 'bottom')) +
  tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE,
               max.raster = c(plot = 1e8, view = 1e8))

tm



The problem appears with rasters only. I never saw a clipped vector. This raster was also trimmed so I cannot say that this one has different extent compared to some other that looks ok. Anyway, thank you very much!

@L Tyrone thank you very much, it works! Yes, I did it )
